# What is the possible sum of non real roots$?$

Tags: polynomials, roots, quartics

Consider an equation $$x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+k=0$$ For every real number $k$

> Find the minimum number of non real roots.

> The sum of non real roots can be___

My work:

For the first part I got the right answer, $2$ by using Rule of Signs. But what about second part$?$ I have no idea how to solve that. Maybe we have to some kind of pairing$?$ And unfortunately I am not familiar with discriminant of a quartic function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MartinR Actually I haven't studied maxima and minima of a quartic function till now....so it's difficult for me to understand that solution

Comment: Look at the other answer (and note that the polynomial is the same as yours, except for a factor $8$). As explained there, the sum of *all* roots is given by Vieta's formulas, and the sum of the real polynomials is known because of the symmetry of the polynomial. There is nothing about minima or maxima.

Comment: @MartinR why is $f'(x)=0$ $?$

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are asking. Please have a look at the second half of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/872861/42969 (starting at “We now make use Vieta's formulas”), it contains exactly what you need.

Comment: @MartinR "So $f(x)$ has Local Minima at $x=x_0$ and no Local Maxima. So $f(x)$ must have eactly two Real roots and two Complex Roots." I cant understand this statement.

Comment: @MartinR i got the approach, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+k\implies f'(x)=4x^3-6x^2+4x-1$
As $f''(x)=12x^2-12x+4>0, \forall x \in \Re$, $f''(x)=0$ does not have real roots, then by reverse logic of Rolle's theorem $f(x)=0$ will have at most 2 real roots.

$f'(x)=0$ has only one real root at $x=1/2$, $f''(1/2)=1>0$. $f(x)$ has only one min at $x=1/2$. $f_{min}=f(1/2)=k-3/16$ if $f_{min}<0 \implies k< \frac{3}{16}$, there will be only two real roots of $f(x)=0.$ Then the sum of all non real roots is 2, when $k>\frac{3}{16}$.

Next, luckily $f(x)=0$ can also be rewritten as $$(2x^2-2x+1)^2=1-4k \implies x=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{-1\pm 2\sqrt{1-4k}}\right).$$

One can check that when $k<\frac{3}{16}$ only 2 roots of $f(x)=0$ are real and sum of these real roots is 1. Next, when $k>\frac{3}{16}$, there is no real root.